# Issue with Lucid and sending tokens

Tags: lucid

Any ideas of why this isn't working? I obviously removed the Blockfrost ID and address, and I have enough tokens to send. For some reason it keeps saying Inputs Exhausted. Any help appreciated.

```js
import { Blockfrost, Lucid } from "/mod.js";

const lucid = await Lucid.new(
  new Blockfrost("https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0", "mainnet...")
);

// Assumes you are in a browser environment
const api = await window.cardano.nami.enable();
lucid.selectWallet(api);

const policyId = "2b28c81dbba6d67e4b5a997c6be1212cba9d60d33f82444ab8b1f218";

const tx = await lucid.newTx()
  .payToAddress("addr1...", { [policyId]: 100n })
  .complete();

const signedTx = await tx.sign().complete();

const txHash = await signedTx.submit();

console.log(txHash);
```

Answer (score 1):

A token has two components, it's name & corresponding policy-id. Thus, instead of `.payToAddress("addr1...", { [policyId]: 100n })` you need to do `.payToAddress("addr1...", { [token]: 100n })` where `token` is defined as concatenation of policy-id & name, like `const token = policyId + tokenName`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not following. 

Can you write out the full script so I can try and understand what you are trying to correct?

Comment: Let's say that the name of the token you wish to send is "BTC" (const tokenName = "BTC"). So  as mentioned in this answer, you need to update payToAddress like payToAddress("addr1...", { [policyId + fromText(tokenName)]: 100n }). You can import "fromText" from "/mod.js" itself.